# How do C#.NET projects determine dependencies with dot notation?

Tags: c#

I am being introduced to the C# language (pretty sure it's .NET framework also but this may be irrelevant) at my work.  I am using Jetbrains/Rider as my IDE (however this is also probably irrelevant).

My question is an obvious one to anyone looking at the code.  I see folders which have dots in the name.  I also see that the references to these files in the code use dot notation to denote the file hierarchy.  My question is, what happens when there is a conflict which is definitely possible given this structure.

Here is an example: (a made up one not from our code)

Actual file structure (indentations denote sub-folders, f denotes folder):

```
MyApp (f)
  Main (f)
    Stuff.cs
  Core.cs
MyApp.Main (f)
  Stuff.cs
MyApp.Main.Stuff (f)
  MoreStuff.cs
```

This file structure is obviously ridiculous but I see no reason why it coudn't be done this way.  Now what if you reference the Stuff.cs file this way

```
using MyApp.Main.Stuff;

namespace MyApp.Main
{
  //whatever
}
```

How does C# resolve this?

Comment: "_Now what if you reference the Stuff.cs file this way_" No, you do **NOT** reference source files with that. You reference a **namespace** with the `using` directive. The namespace needs to be declared **somewhere** (either somewhere in **any** of the source code files of your project or in any of the assemblies your project explictly or implicitly (like the BCL) references.

Comment: So, you are talking about [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces). They **do not need to match directory structure** (unlike in java, e.g.).

Comment: Namespaces are the important part here not the folders.

Comment: One more thing about your example: Theoretically, both Stuff.cs files could contribute to _the same_ class. => [partial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)

Comment: @Fildor neat! that's not confusing at all.  is this something people actually do?

Comment: @DallasCaley Absolutely. It's useful in larger classes (which should be avoided if possible), but I've also used it to extend auto-generated classes, like with Entity Framework. The main file is auto-generated and shouldn't be edited, but it's declared `partial`, so you can create a second file and add properties/methods. The file name should start with the class name still. e.g. MyClass.extended.cs

Comment: Yep, people do. They maybe would arrange and name differently. But partial classes are in fact pretty neat for specific use cases. Some UI things for example or Code Generators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The folder structure and file names don't matter. The namespaces and class names are what matter.

There are some exceptions, like the `App_Data` and [`App_Code`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100)#app_code-folder) folders, and [`Global.asax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178473(v=vs.100)#life-cycle-events-and-the-globalasax-file) file in ASP.NET, and the [`Main` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line) in console apps.

However, matching the class name to the file name and the namespace to the folder structure makes it much easier to find the right file in your project, particularly in bigger projects.

Comment: i think i get it.  out of curiosity how does C# determine which files are part of a project?

Comment: They are listed in the csproj file.

Comment: @GabrielLuci actually it's not true for .net core/5+ projects (so for several years already). SDK csproj files have some defaults: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview. For example I work on a large project now with 200+ . NET projects and not a single .csproj lists .cs files.

Comment: I would also add that folder structure matters a lot when you switch from Visual Studio to for example Visual Studio Code, because then your folder structure is exactly what you see in IDE, and it's better be good for ease of navigation.

Comment: @Evk Yeah, I should have added that. In cases where there is no csproj file, all compilable files in the folder are compiled.

Comment: But there is .csproj file in this case. Because it refers SDK - this sdk has configured defaults about what files to include (as descirbed by the link I included above). For example if we have .csproj targeting Microsoft.NET.Sdk - all .cs files in folder of .csproj file and all subfolders are included by default.